# How does the community bot cast close votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I recently marked a question as a duplicate ([here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38304/5705)).  When I came back later to look at it I noticed that it had been closed and the only two votes were from me and the [Community ♦](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bot-user moderator.  How does this bot cast close votes?

Comment: It seems the OP is prompted to confirm if their question is a duplicate. If they click yes, then the question is closed by Community ♦. *I can't find an official source for this though..* Another way this can happen is if a user that voted to close is subsequently deleted.

Comment: @gandalf3 I think *the feature* was first mentioned with this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes but it is only in this answer that it is explicitly mentioned that Community will be listed as a close voter: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930

Comment: @RayMairlot Excellent! You appear to be gifted with the ability to find anything ;)